# ExtJS with TinyMCE build error

Tags: extjs, tinymce, extjs4.2

I am using [TinyMCE plugin](http://harrydeluxe.github.io/extjs-ux/example/form/tinymce.html) with ExtJS. Everything works OK but when i try to create application build, i am getting error:

> com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error has occurred: Failed Parsing TinyMCEWindowManager.js

Any ideas?

Thanks